# Import CSV or JSON file to DynamoDB using PHP

Tags: php, json, csv, amazon-dynamodb

I have a table on DynamoDB.
I want to upload a CSV (or JSON, whatever file you say is better) to my table at DynamoDB using my PHP script.

I have six attributes in my DynamoDB table:

```
|name(S)|price(N)|category(S)|summary(S)|sale(BOOL)|salePrice(N)|
```

And a CSV file with 5 items, each item with the above 6 attributes. If needed I can convert the file to a JSON file.

How can I upload the CSV file (or JSON) to my DynamoDB table using PHP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please note that there is no straight forward way (i.e. like mongoimport tool of MongoDB) to upload the CSV or JSON files into DynamoDB directly.

**Option 1:-**

You can use [Data Pipeline](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/latest/DeveloperGuide/dp-importexport-ddb.html) to import data into DynamoDB table

**Option 2:-**

Write code to read data from file and can use [batch write item](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/LowLevelPHPBatchOperationsExample.html) API to load the data into DynamoDB table